# Building ruby 2.4.1 (windows) - configure 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby, windows, build

This is my first time to try to build ruby from source on Windows. I try to build ruby 2.4.1 because I dont see it on rubyinstaller.org

I installed devkit then try to do "configure" and get this.

```
D:\src\ruby-2.4.1\ruby-2.4.1>.\win32\configure
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is this error and how to fix this? Ruby does not run make by default but using nmake on Windows?

Any step by step guide to build ruby on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

> What is this error and how to fix this?

`nmake` is part of Microsoft Visual C++. It should have been installed together with Visual Studio or however else you installed Visual C++.

> Ruby does not run make by default but using nmake on Windows?

The Visual C++ build of YARV (I assume that's what you mean by "Ruby", otherwise your post doesn't make much sense, since "Ruby" is a programming language, i.e. a piece of paper, not a piece of software that you can compile) uses the Visual C++ build tools, including `nmake`.

> Any step by step guide to build ruby on Windows?

I don't know of anything that is better and more up-to-date than [the official instructions in `win32/README.win32`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/win32/README.win32).

Comment: I follow the guide but compilation not successful yet. Getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307369/error-ruby-h106-error-c2118-negative-subscript-when-compile-ruby-2-4-1-on-wi