# Error when compile ruby 2.4.1 on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, build

I try to compile ruby 2.4.1 on ruby. after configure I run nmake but getting this error.

nmake

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        CC = cl -nologo
        LD = cl -nologo
        LDSHARED = cl -nologo -LD
        CFLAGS = -MD -Zi -W2 -wd4100 -wd4127 -wd4210 -wd4214 -wd4255 -wd4574  -wd4668 -wd4710 -wd4711 -wd4820 -wd4996  -we4028 -we4142 -O2sy-  -Zm600
        XCFLAGS = -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.ext/include/x64-mswin64_140 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/9.0.0
        CPPFLAGS =  -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600
        DLDFLAGS = -incremental:no -debug -opt:ref -opt:icf -dll
        SOLIBS =
compiling main.c
main.c
d:\ruby\ruby-2.4.1\ruby-2.4.1\include\ruby/ruby.h(106): error C2118: negative subscript
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

**I look at ruby.h (106) and see this:**

```
typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_voidp[SIZEOF_VOIDP == sizeof(void*) ? 1 : -1];
```

How can we fix this? Any of you successfully compile ruby 2.4.1 on Windows?

Comment: Please skip this. I found the project to compile ruby on Windows and for dowload Ruby on Windows. https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases